# File Write Operation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to write into a file in javascript.I tried below Code.I got error like"FileWriter is not defined".please help me in this.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
 <input type = "button" value = "write" onclick="WriteFile()">
<script>

function WriteFile()
{
var fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\Users\ananthi\Desktop\readme.txt");
fileWriter.open() ; 
fileWriter.writeLine("Another line") ; 
fileWriter.close() ;

}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `FileWriter()` is a Java class. Java != Javascript.

Comment: And JavaScript executed in the browser can't write files. Forget about it.

Comment: @IKavanagh: It was also a part of the now-defunct [File Writer API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/), so not just a Java thing. Just the same name used for something similar in a browser API.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Was not aware of that. The use of it here is still Java though. I can't find much on it except [this](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/filewriter.md.html) which shows completely different usage to the question.

Comment: @IKavanagh: Yeah. Well, it's a defunct API that was never widely-supported, so...

Comment: Due to security restriction, you cannot "secretly" (i.e. programmatically, without user intervention) save data locally, but you can prompt the user for downloading a file, and he will decide to save/overwrite to a local file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [File Writer API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) is defunct and never saw significant browser support.

You cannot write files from browser-based JavaScript. What you do instead is provide the user with a link that they can download, like this:

```
var filename = "readme.txt";
var text = "Text of the file goes here.";
var blob = new Blob([text], {type:'text/plain'});
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = filename;
link.innerHTML = "Download File";
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

That works on browsers that support the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (which [modern ones do](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi), but not IE9 or earlier).

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use button call function:

```js
<input type = "button" value = "write" onclick="Download()">

Download () {
        let filename = "readme.txt";
        let text = "Text of the file goes here.\n1";
        let blob = new Blob([text], {type:'text/plain'});
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = filename;
        //link.innerHTML = "Download File";
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.removeChild(link);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        }, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Clear and compact. Works fine.