# How to save the blob for media file?

Tags: javascript, blob

I successfully make the wave data and get type and wave like this below.

then I use `createObjectURL` and it gives me the url `http://localhost:3003/5025f231-f5d0-49f5-9851-600376de0065` but there is nothing.

How can I make the real file??

Any help appreciated...

```
console.log(type); //wave
console.log(data); //Blob {size: 6791616, type: "audio/wav"}
if (type == 'wav'){
 //how can I save the .wav file from blob and give the parameter for user?
      var dlUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data)
      console.log(dlUrl); //it shows http://localhost:3003/5025f231-f5d0-49f5-9851-600376de0065, but there is no 5025f231-f5d0-49f5-9851-600376de0065 file.
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326973/file-write-operation-in-javascript

Comment: If in your code `data` is a Blob, I would expect that `dlUrl` would be prefixed with "blob:". So make sure you are not removing this prefix - something like `blob:http://localhost:3003/5025f231-f5d0-49f5-9851-600376de0065` is a temporary url for what is already on the client machine, while `http://localhost:3003/5025f231-f5d0-49f5-9851-600376de0065` would be a call server call to `localhost:3003`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to add a `blob:` in front of the url:

```js
console.log(type); //wave
console.log(data); //Blob {size: 6791616, type: "audio/wav"}
if (type == 'wav'){
 //how can I save the .wav file from blob and give the parameter for user?
      var dlUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data)
      console.log('blob:' + dlUrl); //it shows http://localhost:3003/5025f231-f5d0-49f5-9851-600376de0065 and there is 5025f231-f5d0-49f5-9851-600376de0065 file.
}
```

Comment: wow thank you, I access "blob:http://localhost:3003/4068625b-975c-47b5-878e-9322a5298532' audio file starts!!